# How to find specific neighbors in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an exercise where I have a 2D array in Java. I take user input, a String, that looks something like "F3 F7" and I mark the coordinates given on the array. Please see below picture.

[2DArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ussZ4.png)

My problem is the fact that I need to check the neighbors of the input to make sure that future inputs do not touch (neither vertically, nor horizontally).

I found the below code in a post here, but I simply do not have the inspiration on how to implement it in order to check only for a specific set in the array.

```java
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        for (x = Math.max(0, i - 1); x <= Math.min(i + 1, array.length); x++) {
            for (y = Math.max(0, j - 1); y <= Math.min(j + 1,
                    array[i].length); y++) {
                if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < array.length
                        && y < array[i].length) {
                    if(x!=i || y!=j){
                    System.out.print(array[x][y] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: So I need to find the neighbors of the marked places (please see the picture I inserted) in a 2D array of strings.